# hiding backside smoothly at flip-card animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple flip card animation where I need to hide the backface layer when not shown.

Problem is, that `hide()` and `show()` can only be called at the beginning or ending (via `transitionend`) of the animation which of course does not look very smooth. Has anybody got an idea how to grab the halftime moment where a change in visibility would not be recognizable?

PS: I know, that in this example hiding would not be necessary because the use of `backface-visibility: hidden;`, but my original script has a couple of virtual backsides and frontsides. So I need to hide all sides that are currently not active.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.trigger-down', function() {
  $(".card").addClass("flip-down-now");
  $(".front").hide();
  $(".back").show();
});
$(document).on('click', '.trigger-up', function() {
  $(".card").attr('class', 'card').addClass("flip-up-now");
  $(".front").show();
  $(".back").hide();
});
```

```css
.card-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  perspective: 1200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4vw;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4vw;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.front {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  display: none;
}

.flip-down-now {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-up-now {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content front">
      <button class="trigger-down">down</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content back">
      <button class="trigger-up">up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframesV) allow you to specify a sequence of animation steps, for example, a 90 degree rotation followed by a sudden scaling down to 0, followed by another 90 degree rotation. (The scale to 0 is the "replacement" for the hidden backface visibility.)

The following snippet styles the front and back faces with animations based on such a keyframe. Whenever the card is flipped, the `<div>` elements "inserted before themselves" in order to restart their animation. (Perhaps someone knows a more elegant way to achieve this.)

```js
function flip() {
  document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(div) {
    div.classList.toggle("back");
    div.parentNode.insertBefore(div, div);
  });
}
```

```css
@keyframes flip {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1) rotateY(90deg);
  }
  51% {
    transform: scale(0) rotateY(90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div:not(.back) {
  animation: flip 0.5s reverse forwards;
}

div.back {
  animation: flip 0.5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="flip()">Flip</button>
<div>Front</div>
<div class="back">Back</div>
```

Comment: I like that looks really cool

Comment: News! https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/ . Please try it with `0.1s` at animation. Byebye

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution now, that is definitely not elegant (and I will therefore not mark it as correct answer) but it prevents me from rewriting the whole code. As I know the animation is timed at 0.6 Seconds I can use jquery `delay()` and `fadeIn()` to change at 50%.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.trigger-down', function() {
  $(".card").attr('class', 'card').addClass("flip-down-now");
  $(".front").delay( 300 ).fadeOut(0);
  $(".back").delay( 300 ).fadeIn(0);
});
$(document).on('click', '.trigger-up', function() {
  $(".card").attr('class', 'card').addClass("flip-up-now");
  $(".front").delay( 300 ).fadeIn(0);
  $(".back").delay( 300 ).fadeOut(0);
});
```

```css
.card-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  perspective: 1200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4vw;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4vw;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.front {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  display: none;
}

.flip-down-now {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-up-now {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content front">
      <button class="trigger-down">down</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content back">
      <button class="trigger-up">up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```